# How to prevent fingerprint scanner from being chosen as a gamepad?

Tags: android, fingerprint, gamepad

My game uses the InputManager to iterate through all device IDs, choosing ones that have Joystick and Gamepad flags set. The problem is that some devices (the LG V35 ThinQ for example) are registering their Fingerprint Scanners as Keyboard|Joystick|Gamepad which is messing things up for my users. Is there a more fool-proof way of detecting actual Gamepad/Joystick devices or is this a bug for LG to solve?

Here's a picture of some Log output of the device that's being chosen.
[image: Log output of fingerprint scanner device]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking the Location flag too? If location is set to "built-in"  there is 99% chance that this is not the device you want to use.

Comment: The "Location" that gets printed out is mIsExternal in the InputDevice class which has an isExternal() accessor but it's not exposed to the public.